# ADPU Service in iOS

Tags: ios, nfc, apdu, contactless-smartcard, hce

I'm looking for an NFC solution for iOS similar to HostApduService for Android. Can someone tell me how can I exchange APDU commands in iOS.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. The only operation mode of NFC that the iPhone (6) currently supports is card emulation through an embedded secure element. iOS does not provide interfaces for other modes of operation (like host card emulation, reader/writer mode or peer-to-peer mode).